# Vfr Reader implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, vfr-reader

I have a web api on the backend which serves a pdf and i want to show the PDF in my ios app. I was able to get it working with a UIWebView. However its not very pretty and i came across this vfr reader.
Will i be able to use vfr-reader to show the pdf from web? 
The example on the vfr-reader page retrieves the pdf from the local documents directory. Has anyone worked with documents downloaded from the web?

Do i have to save the pdf downloaded from web into the documents folder? I dont want users to save the pdf frequently and deplete their storage.

Thanks!